# Is it possible to use type-graphql buildSchema method with classes annotated with @Resolver from nestjs/graphql?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

I'm trying to mock my schema generated with NestJS, the resolvers are using the @Resolver annotation from `@nestjs/graphql`.

I've seen that to mock an schema you need to use `addMockFunctionsToSchema` 
 method, so for building it, I'm using the `buildSchema` from `type-graphql` but I'm getting an `Error: Generating schema error`.

Is it because nestjs don't use the same `@Resolver` annotation than `type-graphql` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to `console.log` the "Generating schema error" and check the reason in `error.originalError` property.

Without resolvers you have no `Query` type so the schema won't work with `graphql-js`. You might pass the `skipCheck` option to the `buildSchema` to get only the types.

Comment: Thanks Michal !, I solved it by adding the proper decorators together with the ones from `@nestjs/graphql`, https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/135#issuecomment-529147747 , thanks again for your work with `type-graphql`.